# C language server on Zed for SDL

Tags: c, clang, sdl, intellisense, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to learn SDL in C and I want to use Zed as my text editor.

In VS code I managed to include the path of the library and get the SDL syntax supported.

Lately Zed has been my main text editor and I'd like to write on it further, but I can't find any way to get SDL syntax supported.

I went through all of Zed's settings multiple times and I can't find anything relevant.

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't an editor plugin for `SDL` (or any other _library_). Mostly plugins for _languages_ (e.g. C, C++, Rust, zig, etc.). There might be some macros, key shortcuts, you could add for some common things (e.g. indentation). SDL does _not_ have any SDL specific _syntax_. Only a [large] list of API _functions_.  The "syntax" here is the syntax for C and/or C++. So, _what_ SDL-specific things are you thinking that you need? For example, checking arguments to function calls need a compiler of sorts. Generally, not the province of a text editor.

Comment: They use Clangd for code completion, right? Then just enable `compile_commands.json` generation in your build system, and any library should be picked up automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used bear -- make to generate a compile_commands.json file. Thanks @HolyBlackCat!